# Use typescript interfaces for passed props in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created this using typescript:

```js
import React, {FC} from 'react';
interface Interface {
    name:string,
    age:number
}
const Home: React.FC<Interface> = (info) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{info.name}</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;

///

const info = {name:'Boris', age:45}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Home info={info}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

...but i get an error from typescript:
`Type '{ info: { name: string; age: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Interface & { children?: ReactNode; }'.   Property 'info' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Interface & { children?: ReactNode; }'`
Question: How to avoid this and why it appeared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code here:

```
interface Interface {
    name:string,
    age:number
}
const Home: React.FC<Interface> = //...
```

Says that the component `Home` expects 2 props: `name` and `age`.

This code here:

```
<Home info={info}/>
```

Passes in one prop named `info`.

---

So you either want to pass in `name` and `age` as props:

```
<Home name={info.name} age={info.age}/>
```

---

Or you want to declare the `info` prop:

```
interface Props {
    info: {
        name:string,
        age:number,
    }
}
const Home: React.FC<Props> = ({ info }) => { /* ... */ }

// Pass props like:
<Home info={info}/>
```

(Note the `({ info })` destructuring assignment, which assigns the `info` prop the to local variable `info`.)

[Playgorund](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeAxAYQF84AzKCEOAcilQ2oG4BYAKDeADsYkpT0kcAAoUwAZ1xs40uF1IQAXJNYzVcTihBIFYmFC4BzTFLXSUB7ZwCuIAEa9jKmUTYvWaCJ11wAEpW2I9DAAdIQAPCIQ4gB8cAC8cAAUOLKc8nBEAJTxsTgm0nQwVlCcSflqYQAmwABu0eWm0mEAFgCM0ThyEMEaWkRhAPRt9U6mg9V15ZksrEQzbEgAHpCwcJVI-FYANvB+WvOsA0dsbB5e8F3xuL3a1ABC0MBi1Njm2gAsAKxubKRWnBhgJ44ABBMBgRLZPJOQrFUqJcpVWpwNBbFBiMQAOU0SDiACIwWA8SMxntBF04p00hAiAMSTJxrV6dNXEA)

Answer (score 0):

You should destruct your props in `Home` component.

So it should be

```
const Home: React.FC<Interface> = ({ info }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{info.name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```